# Need help identifying how to make a function selectable using table() clause and a custom data type

Tags: oracle, plsql, datatypes, table, type-conversion

I would like to be able to run the following code to select records:

**Desired Syntax**

```
select * from table(my_new_package.get_data(123))
```

I have been successful in creating code that compiles, but I am unable to retrieve the data using the above syntax. Could anyone identify how I could update this to ensure the above query will run properly.

Here is the current code:

**Package Spec**

```
create or replace package my_new_package is

  -- Types
  -------------
  type my_data_type is record (
      myfield1          VARCHAR2(10)
      ,myfield2         VARCHAR2(10)
    );
    
   type my_data_type_TABLE is table of my_data_type index by binary_integer;

   -- Functions
   -------------
   FUNCTION get_data(i_id_number varchar2) return my_data_type_table;

end my_new_package;
```

**Package Body**

```
create or replace package body my_new_package is

  function get_data(i_id_number varchar2) return my_data_type_table IS  
    current_row my_data_type;
    all_rows my_data_type_table;
    n integer;

    -- Will update the cursor to pull real data
    cursor cur is
      select '1' myfield1, '10' myfield2 from dual
      union all
      select '2' myfield1, '20' myfield2 from dual
    ;
  BEGIN    
    n := 0;
    for rec in cur LOOP
      n := n+ 1;
      current_row := rec;
      -- do some things to current row

      -- Add modified current row
      all_rows(n) := current_row;
    END LOOP;
    
    return all_rows;
  END;


end my_new_package;
```

The above code compiles, but I can't select from the data using the desired syntax.

Is there anyway to do this where the custom types are embeded at the package level only and not created at the database level?

This will be for Oracle 12 (and Oracle 19).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't select"?

Comment: I want to run "select * from table(my_new_package.get_data('123'))" and receive results similar to if I were running "select * from anyOtherTable". IE: I want the output to mimic as if I were selecting from a real table.

Comment: I understand what you want; I don't understand why you can't.

Comment: When running "select * from table(my_new_package.get_data('123'))", I receive ORA-00902: Invalid datatype. When I run "select * from my_new_package.get_data('123')" I get ORA-00933: Sql command not properly ended.

Comment: You should add these details as part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function as pipelined. Below works in 19c.

Package header:

```
create or replace package my_new_package is

  -- Types
  -------------
  type my_data_type is record (
      myfield1          VARCHAR2(10)
      ,myfield2         VARCHAR2(10)
    );
    
   type my_data_type_TABLE is table of my_data_type;

   -- Functions
   -------------
   FUNCTION get_data(i_id_number varchar2) return my_data_type_table pipelined;

end my_new_package;
/
```

Package body:

```
create or replace package body my_new_package is

  function get_data(i_id_number varchar2) return my_data_type_table pipelined IS  
    current_row my_data_type;
    all_rows my_data_type_table;
    n integer;

    -- Will update the cursor to pull real data
    cursor cur is
      select '1' myfield1, '10' myfield2 from dual
      union all
      select '2' myfield1, '20' myfield2 from dual
    ;
  BEGIN    
    n := 0;
    for rec in cur LOOP
      n := n+ 1;
      pipe row(rec);
    END LOOP;
    
  END;


end my_new_package;
/
```

Test:

```
select * from table(my_new_package.get_data('A'));

MYFIELD1   MYFIELD2  
---------- ----------
1          10        
2          20
```

Comment: Beautiful. This works. Thank you.